# Difference between two calendar dates

Tags: bash, date, unix, julian-date

I have a file with dates in the format YYYYMMDD. I want to find the difference between dates in the file with the current date in julian number.

Comment: Any more detailed information? Input, expected output? What have you done so far?

Comment: This is my question.

`Check a path for specific files. The file format will be like ABCD20131218225516.txt(date & time is appended with file name). Create a month file with details like (Jan  \n Feb  \n Mar 3 …). Get the file date(20131218)of all the files, find the difference with current date in Julian and append the difference number in the month file for file date month. Output should be like this:

Jan, 124, 345
`

Comment: I'm done with first two steps. I need to find difference between the date in filnames with the current date and output should be in julian.

Comment: `I'm done with first two steps` then post your current script in question so that we get some starting point. And don't give information about problem in comment, post all the info you got in question itself.

Comment: @anubhava `ls | grep ".*[20|19][0-9][0-9][01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].txt"` will fetch files with the specified format. Then i have created a month file as mentioned. Next, I have to work with the date difference mentioned which i could not able to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your output format requirement - a date can be in julian (year number and number of days in year), but a difference is just a number of days which doesn't have a 'julian' format.

I don't have a good idea how to do date fiddling in the shell, so i'd resort to perl:

```
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(mktime); sub d2ts { return POSIX::mktime(0, 0, 0, 
substr($_[0],6,2),substr($_[0],4,2)-1,substr($_[0],0,4)-1900); } print 
int((time-d2ts($ARGV[0]))/86400), "\n";' '20131218'

==> 54
```

or

```
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(mktime); sub d2ts { return POSIX::mktime(0, 0, 0, 
substr($_[0],6,2),substr($_[0],4,2)-1,substr($_[0],0,4)-1900); } print 
int((d2ts($ARGV[1])-d2ts($ARGV[0]))/86400), "\n";' '20131218' '20140210'

==> 54
```

The first is to compare one time with 'now', the second is for 2 given dates.

Note that you'll probably have to set your TZ=UTC or you might lose a day over summertime/wintertime switches.